# Jquery-form-plugin implementation to current request call

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a form with multiple file upload as well as others field along, normally I will request jquery ajax to process the data as below, and I can alert all input parameters and pass to server-side to perform certain task.

Since I have upload field in this form, I has acknowledged that is impossible to passes files data through `$('#my_form').serialize()`, I have some search here and know [jquery form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started) can help with this issue, but I don't really get to know how it works, I hope somebody can enlighten me here with working example on how can I implement to above ajax method, and also how can I alert all input values is in post before send to sever-side to process, thanks for help!!!

Here is the current ajax request which is cannot see 'input type "file"' parameter:

```
$('#btn_submit').click(function(){
    var parameters = $('#my_form').serialize();
    var btn = $(this);
    btn.button('loading')
    alert(parameters);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'inc/callback/process.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: parameters,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){

            if(response.success == 'success'){

                $('#successful').show().html('<b>saved!</b>');

            }else{
                $('[id$="_error"]').html('');

                $.each(response.error, function(key, value){
                    if(value){
                        $('#' + key + '_error').html(value);
                    }
                });

            }
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log(arguments);
        }
    }).always(function(){
        btn.button('reset')
    });

});


<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" id="my_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $data->userid ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="list_id" value="<?php echo $listid ?>">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="photo">Photo</label>
        <input type="file" name="files[]" class="multi" accept="gif|jpg" maxlength="3" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="publish"></label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="publish" <?php echo $checked ?>> Publish</div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo $list->name ?>"><span class="error" id="name_error"></span>
    </div>

    <hr />

    <button class="btn btn-success" id="btn_submit" type="button" data-loading-text="Loading...">Save</button>
</form>
```

**EDITED:**

I've been tried the code provided by @Markus Fröhlich, but the form will submitted directly to `inc/callback/process.php`, seems like the ajaxForm doesn't trigger as well as alert never shown!

```
    //this jq is refer as external js file at the bottom before </body>
$("#my_form").ajaxForm({
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function() {
            var btn = $(this);
            btn.button('loading')
            alert(parameters);
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        console.log(percentComplete); // Show the completed percent 
    },
    success: function(response) {

        if(response.success == 'success'){

            $('#successful').show().html('<b>Edited saved!</b>');

        }else{
            $('[id$="_error"]').html('');

            // display invalid error msg
            $.each(response.error, function(key, value){
                if(value){
                    $('#' + key + '_error').html(value);
                }
            });

        }

    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown );
    }

}).always(function(){
        btn.button('reset')
});


<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" id="my_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="inc/callback/process.php">

    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $data->userid ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="list_id" value="<?php echo $listid ?>">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="photo">Photo</label>
        <input type="file" name="files[]" class="multi" accept="gif|jpg" maxlength="3" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="publish"></label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="publish" <?php echo $checked ?>> Publish</div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo $list->name ?>"><span class="error" id="name_error"></span>
    </div>

    <hr />

    <button class="btn btn-success" id="btn_submit" type="submit" data-loading-text="Loading...">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: button type ='submit' changed it to type='button' ,

Comment: I've change to 'button' but that's not an issue. I wanted to know how to use `jquery-form-plugin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should works with ajaxForm! (Not tested!!!)

Don't forget the new **form action**, and the Button Type is now "**submit**".

```
$("#my_form").ajaxForm({
    dataType:  "json",
    beforeSend: function() {
        var btn = $(this);
        btn.button('loading')
        alert(parameters);
     },
     uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
         console.log(percentComplete); // Show the completed percent 
     },
     success: function(response) {
         if(response.success == 'success'){

             $('#successful').show().html('<b>saved!</b>');

         }else{
             $('[id$="_error"]').html('');

         $.each(response.error, function(key, value){
             if(value){
                 $('#' + key + '_error').html(value);
             }
         });

     },
     error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         console.log(errorThrown );
     }
});


<form action="inc/callback/process.php" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" id="my_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $data->userid ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="list_id" value="<?php echo $listid ?>">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="photo">Photo</label>
            <input type="file" name="files[]" class="multi" accept="gif|jpg" maxlength="3" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="publish"></label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="publish" <?php echo $checked ?>> Publish</div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo $list->name ?>"><span class="error" id="name_error"></span>
        </div>

        <hr />

        <button class="btn btn-success" id="btn_submit" type="submit" data-loading-text="Loading...">Save</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: I've tested and the page is redirect to `inc/callback/process.php` instead.

Comment: I'm using bootstrap as a website layout and all javascript/jquery libraries will put in the end of `</body>`, would it cause a problem?

Comment: Look at this example from the Plugin Owner:
http://malsup.com/jquery/form/progress.html

No this is no problem, you should also test it with Firebug (Firefox Plugin)